# How to shift the div on the right without moving the one on the left in a flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my code:

```
<div class="flex-container fb-jc-center fb-ai-center">
  <div>
      first div
  </div>
  <div>
      second div
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  
}

.fb-jc-center{
  justify-content:center;
}
.fb-ai-center {
    align-items: center;
}
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/0w1sk2au/

As you can see my two div are perfectly centered but I would like to shift the one on the right without moving the one on the left.

I tried:

```
.flex-container > div:nth-child(2){
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

but it doesn't work because it moves the first div too.

I think I can add an empty element with a 20 px width:

```
<div class="flex-container fb-jc-center fb-ai-center">
  <div>
      first div
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
      <div id="empty"></div>
      <div>second div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#empty{
   width:20px;
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do it ?

Comment: Hello, please use snippet when you enter code. There is no need for a jsfiddle for that... For your problem, have you tried `margin-right: -20px` on your second flex item?

Comment: Hello @Amaury Hanser ,I tried right now thanks to your comment but it moves the first div to the right and I want to keep it unmoved

Comment: Add `margin-left` for `.flex-container > div`

Comment: @s.Kuznetsov it works, thanks. Post your answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shift `#red` to the right without losing location for `#blue`, set rule `margin-left` for selector `.flex-container > div`.

The *secret* of this solution is to apply this css rule for both `div`, which means that the left margin of the `#blue` div is compensated.